# Div shifts when content added to page

Tags: html, css

Before I start, here's the code of my entire page html:

```
<div align="center">
<img src="http://questers.x10.bz/Header.png" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -440px; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;" class="rotate" />
</div>
<p></p> 
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='blog.php'>Blog</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Wiki</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Trivia</a></li>
<li><a href='admin/login.php'>Admins</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div style="box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; background: #fff; margin-top: 320px; margin-left: 235px; position: absolute; padding: 10px; width: 655px; max-width: 655px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Create New Post</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Delete Post</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog Home Page</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>Statics</h3>
<p>Total Blog Posts: 0</p>
<p>Total Blog Comments: 0</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#mainbox {
     width: 655px;
     background: #fff;
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
     padding: 10px;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 320px;
     margin-left: 235px;
    }
```

This makes the site page look like this:

However when you add any more content to the site, such as another paragraph, it looks like this (it shifts and changes width):

Instructions on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a container around it that has a fixed position and width, and then add the mainbox inside of that container.

I am sort of struggling to see what the actual issue is, so if you could explain it further that would be much more beneficial to the people on this site.

Code for container:

```
#container{
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  width:600px;
}
```

Place this after the navbar code and contain all of the body stuff in it, so the main content boxes.

Comment: The issue is that the div shifts - if you look at the screenshots which I provided, the top left-hand tip of the div moves right.

Comment: Yeah, put everything in a container of fixed width, so that it is <div id="container> and not creating separate div's floating around on the page. Then, anything you put in that container, you can set the width to be 100%. Let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Infact, I have a different idea. I assume that everything is in the CENTER of the page? If so, then use margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; in the CSS. This will center the div

Comment: Yeah in that case make a container and then use margin-left:auto; -- Are you planning to place another content box to the right of that one?

Comment: I did already have one there, but I removed it because it may be the cause of the issue. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: If I put the whole site into one container, they all stay in one place - could you post a code example please?

Comment: Amazing, that seems to of worked for the moment! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. In future, please don't write 8 comments demanding help! People will stumble along if they can help and if they can't they will move on :)

Answer (score 0):

I made this changes for you! I think this is a better html markup.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
 background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;

}
.center {
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.image {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
}
.rotate {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rotate:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
 -o-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background .5s ease;
}
#cssmenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  padding: 0 50px;
}
.wrap {
  width: 1070px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3ab4a6;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
 background: #226c63;
 transition: background .5s ease;
}


#mainbox {
 width: 655px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 320px;
 margin-left: 235px;
}
.content {
background: #fff;
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
 background: #fff; 
 width: 655px; 
 max-width: 655px;
}
.content ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Admin - All Things Roblox</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    <li><a href='blog.php'>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Wiki</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Trivia</a></li>
    <li><a href='admin/login.php'>Admins</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="wrap">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://questers.x10.bz/Header.png" style="" class="rotate" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Create New Post</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delete Post</a></li>
          <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Statics</h3>
        <p>Total Blog Posts: 0</p>
        <p>Total Blog Comments: 0</p>
        <p>Total Blog Comments: 0</p>
        <p>Total Blog Comments: 0</p>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```